# How do I create a formula in which a compounded numeric variable equals a specified value?

Tags: javascript

If you clicked on this post, I know the question is a little bit unclear. So I have to show you what I mean instead.

```
var value = 30;
var num = 1;
var total = 0;

while(num < 10){

total +=num;
num++;

}
if(total == value){
console.log("They are equivalent");
}
```

Alright consider the variables **value**, **num**, and **tota**l. While num is less than 10, the specified value. I want it to add  the num value into total, but at the end of the loop I want total and value to be equivalent. I just don't know how to do that or what formula I need to create in order to do that.

Comment: `1+2+3+4+5+6+7 = 28`, and `1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8 = 36`, so how could this work?

Comment: I think you are focusing on the value of the number, and not what I'm saying so let me say it a different way. How can I make the value of num equal  the variable value if it has been looped over 10 times. Whether the value is 30 , 50,  or 1000. What formula would I need to do to make num value equal the variable value when it has been looped over 10 times

Comment: I think it would help if you gave us a few examples. Give us a function input, and what it should output.

Comment: What is allowed to happen in the while loop? Can `num` be larger than 10 in the loop? Does `num` have to be incremented by 1 each loop cycle? etc... If you want `1+2+3+4+5 + 7+8 = 30` and you want `num` to grow in the loop, you will need to use _backtracking_, otherwise you can use a _greedy accumulator_ if `num` is allowed to go from 9 to 0 backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need a factor for your value to add.

If you have just to add the counter, it goes from 1 to 9, the formular for the sum is [Triangular Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)

```
 sum = n * (n + 1) / 2
```

You know the sum, you get `45` and that is to much. For the right sum you need a factor to multiply `num` before adding. This is just the division of

```
wanted result / actual result = factor
      30      /       45      = 2 / 3  = 0.6666666666666667
```

This factor can be used in your iteration.

For accuracy i suggest to use equivalent fractions.

```js
var value = 30,
    num = 1,
    total = 0;

while (num < 10) {
    total += num * 2 / 3; // apply factor
    console.log(num, total);
    num++;
}

if (total === value){
    console.log("They are equivalent");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is computing the sum of an arithmetic progression, also known as an [arithmetic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum), starting from 1 and with a common difference of 1. Mathematically, the progression is:

[image: a1]

[image: d]

[image: an]

And the sum is:

[image: Sn]

---

It sounds to me like you want to calculate the required value of *n* (`num` in your code) for a prespecified value for the sum *S<sub>n</sub>* (`value` in your code). We can accomplish this by solving the above sum equation for *n*.

We can start by rearranging as follows:

[image: Sn-rearrange-1]

[image: Sn-rearrange-2]

This is a [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation). Plugging into the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula):

[image: quad]

---

Here's a demonstration of the above result using [R](https://www.r-project.org/).

First, just to demonstrate the sum formula:

```
calcTotal <- function(num) num*(num+1L)/2L;
calcTotal(1:20);
##  [1]   1   3   6  10  15  21  28  36  45  55  66  78  91 105 120 136 153 171 190 210
```

Now, here's how we can implement the derived solution for *n*. I wrote this function to produce a matrix giving the input *S<sub>n</sub>* value under the `total` column, then the next two columns showing the result value of the derived formula for both the plus  and minus choices for the ± operation.

```
calcNum <- function(total) cbind(total,matrix(rep(each=2L,sqrt(2*total+0.25))*c(1,-1)-0.5,ncol=2L,byrow=T,dimnames=list(NULL,c('+','-'))));
res <- calcNum(1:36);
res;
##       total        +         -
##  [1,]     1 1.000000 -2.000000
##  [2,]     2 1.561553 -2.561553
##  [3,]     3 2.000000 -3.000000
##  [4,]     4 2.372281 -3.372281
##  [5,]     5 2.701562 -3.701562
##  [6,]     6 3.000000 -4.000000
##  [7,]     7 3.274917 -4.274917
##  [8,]     8 3.531129 -4.531129
##  [9,]     9 3.772002 -4.772002
## [10,]    10 4.000000 -5.000000
## [11,]    11 4.216991 -5.216991
## [12,]    12 4.424429 -5.424429
## [13,]    13 4.623475 -5.623475
## [14,]    14 4.815073 -5.815073
## [15,]    15 5.000000 -6.000000
## [16,]    16 5.178908 -6.178908
## [17,]    17 5.352350 -6.352350
## [18,]    18 5.520797 -6.520797
## [19,]    19 5.684658 -6.684658
## [20,]    20 5.844289 -6.844289
## [21,]    21 6.000000 -7.000000
## [22,]    22 6.152067 -7.152067
## [23,]    23 6.300735 -7.300735
## [24,]    24 6.446222 -7.446222
## [25,]    25 6.588723 -7.588723
## [26,]    26 6.728416 -7.728416
## [27,]    27 6.865460 -7.865460
## [28,]    28 7.000000 -8.000000
## [29,]    29 7.132169 -8.132169
## [30,]    30 7.262087 -8.262087
## [31,]    31 7.389867 -8.389867
## [32,]    32 7.515610 -8.515610
## [33,]    33 7.639410 -8.639410
## [34,]    34 7.761356 -8.761356
## [35,]    35 7.881527 -8.881527
## [36,]    36 8.000000 -9.000000
```

First, observe that the choice of minus always results in negative numbers. Since we're only interested in positive results, we can ignore that column.

Second, note how the choice of plus always results in positive numbers, but many of them are non-integers. This makes sense, given that the arithmetic series does not land on all possible integer totals. For totals that satisfy the integer basis of the progression, the function returns the correct integral results.

We can subset out the integral results as follows, using a custom function for proper floating-point comparison:

```
feq <- function(a,b,TOL=max(a,b)*1e-12) if (is.infinite(a) || is.infinite(b)) a==b else abs(a-b)<=TOL;
res[feq(res[,'+'],round(res[,'+'])),];
##      total +  -
## [1,]     1 1 -2
## [2,]     3 2 -3
## [3,]     6 3 -4
## [4,]    10 4 -5
## [5,]    15 5 -6
## [6,]    21 6 -7
## [7,]    28 7 -8
## [8,]    36 8 -9
```

---

Now, for the exact total you have in your code sample:

```
calcNum(30);
##      total        +         -
## [1,]    30 7.262087 -8.262087
```

This means that we would require 7.262087 iterations of your loop in order to arrive at a total value of 30. This is, of course, impossible.

Answer (score -1):

Your calculation wont work to give you 30, if you are looking for that exact compouding method to be equal to value after 9 iterations then use

```
var value =36;
```

This is because

```
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8 =36;
```

This compund method will never give you 30

Comment: This was already mentioned in my comment (Above), and he's clarified that this isn't want he's looking for.

Comment: When i replied my mobile app hadnt refreshed i guess,